# Is there a way to export a .der certificate to .bin file?

Tags: powershell, openssl, x509certificate

I have a x509 .der certificate that I need to concatenate to a .bin package. The problem is that if I use

```
cat mycert.der >> package.bin
```

some of the characters in the certificate are changed. Is there a way to export the certificate in a .bin file using openssl or something? I am using Windows powershell to run commands.

Answer (score 2):

The redirection operator in PowerShell (`>` or `>>`) messes up your binary data, because it applies some encoding based on `$OutputEncoding`. Piping between `Get-Content` and `Set-`/`Add-Content` does not modify your data.

So you can use

```
Get-Content mycert.der -Raw | Add-Content package.bin -NoNewline
```

to append your certificate to your binary as binary data. You need `-Raw` so that PowerShell will preserve any CR/LF bytes and you need `-NoNewline` to prevent PowerShell from adding an own CR/LF at the end.

Comment: I tried using Get-Content but when I compare the content of the certificate with the one concatenated in the bin file, they are different.

Comment: @Harry Update^^

Answer (score 1):

maybe because of windows powershell `cat` replaces line ending `\n` into `\r\n`, can you try to copy file instead

otherwise to convert certificates

from `man openssl` and `man x509`

```
...
   Convert a certificate from PEM to DER format:

    openssl x509 -in cert.pem -inform PEM -out cert.der -outform DER

   Convert a certificate to a certificate request:

    openssl x509 -x509toreq -in cert.pem -out req.pem -signkey key.pem

   Convert a certificate request into a self signed certificate using extensions for a CA:

    openssl x509 -req -in careq.pem -extfile openssl.cnf -extensions v3_ca \
           -signkey key.pem -out cacert.pem
...
```